# how to calculate rem properly in sass?

Tags: css, sass, styles, retina-display

We are for the first time developing an app and the designer has prototyped the layout in **retina modus**, although this is not our goal for the next release, then now what we have to do, is to get the values provided by him and divide by 2.

For instance, we have a label to show a text and the label has the following `scss`:

```
        label {
            font-family: $font-family-medium;
            color: color($colors, slate);
            font-size: 2.25rem / 2;
            letter-spacing: 0.0625rem / 2;
            line-height: 3.25rem / 2;
            white-space: normal;
        }
```

That is the result:

[image]

That looks good, but depending where I apply the code chrome tells that the `css` property is not valid. Ok, then I add the function `calc` to the code above:

```
        label {
            font-family: $font-family-medium;
            color: color($colors, slate);
            font-size: calc(2.25rem / 2);
            letter-spacing: calc(0.0625rem / 2);
            line-height: calc(3.25rem / 2);
            white-space: normal;
        }
```

So chrome stops complaining, but that is the result:

[image]

The text in label gets wayyy smaller.

What is the difference between using `calc` and not using `calc` in sass?

I suppose I'm missing some important layout/design concept?

**UPDATE:**

I just realized that the first code ist for chrome always invalid:

[image]

That is one point that I figured out. So the calculation of retina modus dividing by 2 is not good I guess?

Answer (score 14):

Creating the function

```
@function calculateRem($size) {
  $remSize: $size / 16px;
  @return #{$remSize}rem;
}
```

Creating the mixin

Next we create a mixin that calls the function:

```
@mixin fontSize($size) {
  font-size: $size; //Fallback in px
  font-size: calculateRem($size);
}
```

Sass

```
h1 {
  @include fontSize(32px);
}
```

check this [article](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2013/07/01/easy-peasy-rem-conversion-with-sass/)

Comment: How would i get this to accept multiple values like `calculateRem(20px, 30px, 50px)`?

Whenever I add multiple values the functions returns the values correctly but like this : `padding: 2rem 4rem 1rem/;`

Comment: What's the purpose of the `calculateRem()` function? Why not just write something like `font-size: 1.2rem` directly without using a function?

Comment: It enables the use of px instead of rem for the $size param.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is you are not doing the division, you get in CSS for example the value `0.0625rem / 2` and this is not valid CSS, You have to put in parentheses to get the correct value:

**SCSS**

```
label {
  font-family: arial;
  color:red;
  font-size: (2.25rem / 2);
  letter-spacing: (0.0625rem / 2);
  line-height: (3.25rem / 2);
  white-space: normal;
}
```

**OUTPUT CSS**

```
label {
  font-family: arial;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.03125rem;
  line-height: 1.625rem;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

When you are using `calc()` CSS can do the division by itself.

Comment: you're right !  anyway the title should be how to do right calculation on sass.
Have nothing to do about rems, px, vh....

Answer (score 4):

I use the `rem-calc` function, borrowed from Foundation:

```
$rem-base: 16px;

@function strip-unit($num) {
  @return $num / ($num * 0 + 1);
}

@function convert-to-rem($value, $base-value: $rem-base)  {
  $value: strip-unit($value) / strip-unit($base-value) * 1rem;
  @if ($value == 0rem) { $value: 0; } // Turn 0rem into 0
  @return $value;
}

@function rem-calc($values, $base-value: $rem-base) {
  $max: length($values);
  @if $max == 1 { @return convert-to-rem(nth($values, 1), $base-value); }
  $remValues: ();
  @for $i from 1 through $max {
    $remValues: append($remValues, convert-to-rem(nth($values, $i), $base-value));
  }
  @return $remValues;
}
```

So you can use it like this for example:

`margin: rem-calc(24 0); // output: margin: 1.5rem 0;`

Comment: I'm switching for Foundation to Boostrap and I use this exact function also! :) Thanks for sharing.